# If time between 8:00 AM to 5:30 PM

Tags: powershell

Can someone please mention how I can execute a sendmail function
if the time is between 8:00 AM to 5:30 PM and for the 
rest of the time not send mail ?

Basically something like this pseudo works.

```
if(time between 8:00 AM and 5:30 PM)
{
    send mail
{
else
{
    do nothing
}
```

More like this

```
[int]$hour = get-date -format HH
If($hour -lt 8 -or $hour -gt 17)
{
```

Comment: I don't see the issue. You have the basic idea of what you want to accomplish. Is there a section you don't understand? Do you know how to get your current time? Is it the sending of email you don't understand? Please include your attempt and the specific portion you don't understand how to do.

Comment: I have the code but its not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking Time and executing different instrcutions based on hour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630237/checking-time-and-executing-different-instrcutions-based-on-hour)

Comment: @abmv Can you include the code in your post then?

Comment: Well what does your code look like? We can't tell what's wrong without seeing what you've got and what it does at the moment.

Comment: Have you considered just creating a scheduled task that executes your script in the time window of your choice?

Comment: `$hour -ge 8 -and $hour -le 17` should work for between 8 and 5

Comment: We're downvoting because you're asking us to write code for you. That's not what we're here for. We're here to tell you why the code you wrote isn't working.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Create 2 reference timestamps

```
$min = Get-Date '08:00'
$max = Get-Date '17:30'
```

and compare their `TimeOfDay` properties to the respective property of your date:

```
$now = Get-Date

if ($min.TimeOfDay -le $now.TimeOfDay -and $max.TimeOfDay -ge $now.TimeOfDay) {
  # send mail
}
```

Comment: what about if you need to define from 22:00 to 8:00, for example?
Be careful, because this solution only works when beginning time is lower than ending time.
If $min -gt $max you need to substract one day to $min date {$min.AddDays(-1)}

Answer (score 4):

I was googling to see if someone came up with better solution than mine and got here. Here's how I solve it:

```
if (((get-date).TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes) -in 480..1050) {
    # some code
}
```

I hope it helps someone, cheers! :)

Comment: Some descriptions of the code would be nice. also use variables for start and stop

Answer (score 1):

I like this idea, but I found you have to convert the TotalMinutes to an integer in order for it to be found in the range:

```
if (([int](get-date).TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes) -in 480..1050) {
    # some code
}
```